# Data recovery on locked out Infinix Hot 10

Tags: data-recovery, factory-reset, locked-out, infinix

I had forgotten my PIN on Infinix Hot 10. I am unable to get in without a backup. I got the phone new and didn't create a backup as a first-time Android user, which I had saved important notes in my Android notepad.

My question is, if I factory reset the phone and use a data recovery, will I be able to recover the message in my notepad?

I really need help on this before I make the attempt.

Comment: Android phones are encrypted by default and a factory reset erases the master key making all data inaccessible for your life time and beyond.

Comment: @Robert, why not make that an answer?